# How can I prevent adding tags to the input that have spaces?

Tags: reactjs, button, input, jsx

I did just through pattern="[^\s]+.
It doesn't work, it only works when you submit the entire form.

My button

```
const addTag = () => {
const currentIndex = fields.length - 1;
const currentValue = watch(`tags[${currentIndex}].name`);
if (!currentValue) return;
append("");};
```

Input

```
<input
  className={classes.input}
  name={`tags[${index}].name`}
  ref={register()}
  defaultValue={defaultItem}
  // pattern="[^\s]+"
  />
```

Comment: can you please create a minimal reproducible example so that people can understand your problem.

Comment: there is an input and a button, if the input has a space the button cannot be pressed. or just disallow entering space in the field